# Finding isomorphism of a factor group based on orders.

Tags: abstract-algebra

If |G|=30 and  |Z(G)|=5, what commonly known group is G/Z(G) isomorphic to?

Answer (score 4):

Since $|G/Z(G)|=6$, $G/Z(G)$ is isomorphic to the cyclic group of order 6 or is isomorphic to $S_3$, the symmetric group of degree 3. But if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ must be abelian, and it contradicts from $G\neq Z(G)$. So $G/Z(G)\cong S_3$.

Comment: You mean $S_3$, not $A_3$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you for pointing out my mistake. I'll edit my answer.